# DB2 version 10 percentile_CONT missing

Tags: db2

I am trying to calculate percentile 25th,50th and 75th with in Db2. However, i could not find the aggregate function PERCENTILE_CONT there. I get SQL error package not found. Is there any other way to do this.

Comment: If you look around, you should find ways of archiving the same result using OLAP functions supported on earlier versions  E.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41703865/how-to-output-different-25th-50th-75th-percentiles-in-single-teradata-query

Answer (score 1):

IBM added PERCENTILE_CONT and PERCENTILE_DISC to Db2 for Z/OS starting from Version 12.

For Db2 for Linux/Unix/Windows, IBM added these functions at V11.1.

For earlier versions (you mention V10) you will need to implement your own version of those functions, perhaps as external functions in whatever programming language supported by Db2-for-Z in which you have skills.

Comment: Thanks mao , i was expecting the same. Let me try to write my own.